# Is it possible to disable text truncation in a JButton?

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to prevent text from turning to "..." in very small JButtons?

On my current UI the text fits inside the button just fine on a small font, but it is still turned into "...". Is it possible to disable/change that behavior?

Comment: *"Is it possible to prevent text from turning to "..." in very small JButtons?"* Sure. Let them become their preferred size, or larger.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be being handled in the `paint` method in the `BasicButtonUI` class (and then the `layout` method, and eventually down to the `SwingUtilities2.clipString` method) in the oracle JDK 8 release at least.  Subclassing `BasicButtonUI`, overwriting the `paint` method, and then setting an instance of that subclass as the UI on your button should allow you to overwrite this.